# Cocoa WebKit - Mountain Lion - loadRequest, loadHTMLString:baseURL: - Load Error

Tags: cocoa, webview, webkit

OS X 10.8.2.  I have a webView in which I have been loading HTML documents. (One at a time, in response to user input.)

I am using WebScriptObjects so that when the user clicks on a menu element within each HTML document, my code is notified. I can then create some context-specific document in memory, and serve it back to the user, by calling `loadHTMLString:baseURL` on the webView's mainFrame.

(An aside: a secondary reason for this work was to modify the HTML document, in order to force WebKit to update the page and linked javascript files; WebKit would aggressively cached and reuse javascript, and changes to the linked JS were not being reflected in the WebView. To fix this, I rewrote the javascript include on the fly, time-stamping it, to force WebKit to re-include it. Very tedious. Anyone know if WebKit has improved in this area?)

Before Mountain Lion, the code worked as advertised, with no errors.

Running on Mountain Lion, two breakages have occurred:

1) Fragments are included when getting an `absoluteString` from an NSURL.  i.e. the string "#someAnchor" is appended to the end of the string. Fixed by using the `path` method instead.

2) Subsequent loads no longer work in the webFrame. Specifically... I can load one page (e.g. page1.html) in to the webFrame, either with loadRequest or loadHTMLString:baseURL:. The delegate callbacks received are:

```
webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:
```

followed by...

```
webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:
```

Great success.

**THE PROBLEM:**

But, after clicking on an HTML element that would normally result in a new page load (e.g. page2.html) through the WebScriptObjects, I instead get these callbacks:

```
webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:
```

and...

```
webView:didFailProvisionalLoadWithError:forFrame:
```

The error code is 999 (NSURLErrorCancelled)

A little research shows that this is a very common error, particularly in the iOS world. And that normally, you just ignore it. However, I can't ignore it, as my page loading is broken. This error occurs regardless of the length of time between the initial page load and the next page load attempt. The initial page is fully loaded (as indicated by the `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` callback.)

I have tried calling stopLoading before loading the page, but to no effect.

Can anyone offer suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A work around for this problem: instead of attempting to load the next page immediately, I now schedule it for the very near future using:

```
performSelector: @selector(doScheduledPageChange)
            withObject: nil
            afterDelay: 0.01];
```

This works.